# Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 20.04 tells me there's an update to Core 18

Tags: 20.04, updates

I've been running Ubuntu 20.04 since it came out. Today the Ubuntu Software app is telling me that there's an update to Core 18 ("Runtime environment based on Ubuntu 18.04"). I don't have a update source that appears to cause this. Is software from 18.04 part of 20.04? Should I perform the update?

Comment: You haven't said if you're running a desktop , server or what type of install, however I'll assume from 20.04 you're using a *yy.mm* debian based install. The Core 18 I think it's talking about is a *snap* ("*core18                                  20200427      canonical✓            base   Runtime environment based on Ubuntu 18.04*" as seen with a `snap search core18` on my *groovy* box).  It's talking about the Snap core18 I believe; my *groovy* box having both *core18* and *core20* installed.  Sorry I upgrade packages by terminal so have little experience of how it shows in apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm running desktop. "snap list" shows both "core" and "core18". I don't have "core20". Is the system supposed to have both core18 and core? My naive guess is that core18 shouldn't be present in a 20.04 system.

Comment: I'd suggest waiting for others to respond, or provide input too. I don't see any problem with updating the *snap* (you can updates snaps with `snap refresh`) but my knowledge in this area is incomplete sorry.

Comment: Three core snaps are available, `core` (based on 16.04), `core18` (based on 18.04) and `core20` (based on 20.04). The core snaps are runtime environments, other snaps are built on them. Which of the core snaps are installed in your system depends on other snaps installed, the core snaps are pulled in as dependencies. Since the snap `snap-store` should be installed in your system, `core18` should also be installed. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236201/590937) might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Software app in 20.04 has a bug that notifies the user of an update to a package that isn't installed. If you ignore this notification it disappears the next time you open the Software app and it never comes back.

I have core and core18 snap packages installed in 20.04. core18 was automatically installed as a dependency of another snap package. The software app in 20.04 has a bug in it that it shows an available update for a snap package that isn't installed, for example core16. When you click the Update button a notification pops up that says `Unable to update core: snap has no updates available` as shown in the screenshot, even though the results of `snap list` show that the core16 snapd-runtime environment is not installed. Not only that but core16 does not have a stable channel, only beta and edge candidates, so I ignored the green number next to Updates on the toolbar. The next time I opened the Software app the Update notification for core16 was gone, and it has never reappeared since then.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My search engine brought me here, running **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**.

**Solution**: click the refresh arrow button in the upper left corner. Afterwards the application shows everything is up to date.

My guess it, that `Ubuntu Software` is not properly checking for pending updates

```
$ snap changes
ID   Status  Spawn               Ready               Summary
117  Done    today at 08:41 CET  today at 08:41 CET  Auto-refresh snap "core18"
118  Done    today at 13:37 CET  today at 13:37 CET  Refresh all snaps: no updates
119  Done    today at 13:41 CET  today at 13:41 CET  Refresh all snaps: no updates
```

The erroneous pending update was presented to me at 13:xy, and according to `snap` the `core18` was updated in the morning at 8:41 (13:37 and :41 is me trying `snap refresh` manually)

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu Software]

Answer (score 0):

[Core snap list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTNzq.png)

I have found the same on my system & continue trying to update, then ignore it until the next time the update message appears.