# Why doesn't Snap install Gnome automatically if Firefox can't be opened without it?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, snap

Firefox wasn't opening on Kubuntu for me. When I ran it via terminal I got the following error.

`Error: not connected to gnome-3-38-2004 content interface.`

1. Why does Firefox depends on Gnome on Kubuntu?
2. Why doesn't it gets installed as Firefox dependency?

I am on fresh install of Kubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 4):

1. Firefox Snap is packaged to use the GTK toolkit, which is why it requires gnome components.
2. That that component is not installed as Firefox dependency must have been a glitch during installation. Else, it might be a packaging issue, but that seems unlikely to me: in that case the issue would have been identified and resolved quickly.

Comment: It certainly doesn't seem to be a glitch because of you search this issue you will find lots of posts like this. I nuked Snap folder and then installed Firefox again. So maybe it is because of that but certainly not a promising start for 23.04.

Comment: Please, see also this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462400/removing-old-and-unneeded-snaps#comment2560054_1462406

Comment: @FedKad, thanks. So yes, it could be more than an occasional glitch: it could be a bug.