# Multiple gnome files in /snap

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, storage

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop and checking my storage usage. I have four files in /snap named gnome 3-38-2004, gnome 3-34-1804, gnome 3-28-1804, and gnome 3-26-1604. Do I need all of them?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1236140/590937) might be helpful.