# What Gnomes are in use? Snaps directory is 4.1GB

Tags: gnome, snap, disk-usage, disk-management

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. I seem to have four different snap versions of GNOME on my machine, and they seem to be using quite a large amount of memory. I'd love to be able to remove some, however I'm very wary as to which are machine critical. Is there any way to tell or figure out which versions I can remove? I understand it usually stores two versions from what I've read.

Disk Usage of `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/` :

[image: Disk Usage of /var/lib/snapd/snaps]

Comment: Is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1236140/590937) helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify snaps on my system I no longer need?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236140/how-to-identify-snaps-on-my-system-i-no-longer-need)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you only have two versions of GNOME installed: 42-2204 and 38-2204, two version (current and previous) each. As you correctly say, snap keeps a minimum of one older version, so you cannot remove any of the GNOMEs - unless one of them is not needed anymore, as no other snaps needs them.
To check, you can run

```
grep "default-provider:\|base:" /snap/*/current/meta/snap.yaml | awk '{print $NF}'
```

In case a snap like one of the GNOME snaps doesn't appear in the list, it should be safe to remove.